# s3.putObject doesn't fail. but doesn't upload image

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file using Node to S3.

I have the following code:

```
let md = {
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    ContentType: fileItem.mimetype,
    ContentLength: fileItem.size,
    Key: key,
    Body: fileItem.buffer,
    ACL: "public-read"
};
this.s3.putObject(md, function(error, response) {
    console.log("S3 ERROR");
    console.log(error);
    console.log(response);
});
```

However when I try to use this code, I get the following:

```
S3 ERROR
null
{ ETag: '"b14a13596481fa385da35cb5c7d8073a"' }
```

Making it look like the operation was successful.

However when I check my bucket, I don't see any file.

Comment: If you received an `ETag`, then the upload was successful. As a test, perhaps you could try hard-coding the `Bucket` and `Key` values, then check for the object?

Comment: Nice questions. +5 for today.